# Can I set the script source of a worker using Chrome Debugging Protocol?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to edit script sources as they are loaded in Chrome.

I'm successfully listening to the event `scriptParsed` of the Debugger domain as described in the Chrome Debugging Protocol. I'm using this to then call `Debugger.setScriptSource` to modify the script. This all works well except for Workers where I don't get a corresponding `scriptParsed`.

Is it possible to do the same thing for Workers?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a theoretical attempted answer, as I haven't written any code to test this idea yet.

There's [`Target`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Target/) domain in the protocol that should handle worker events. It took me a while to figure it out. I noticed an [old fork](https://paulirish.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Worker/) of the [Chrome Debugging Protocol Viewer](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot), which had a `Worker` domain, but it's not in the live one. I later found in the [commits](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/14d5ae1493499885e5f9820490e77aef43d0d083) that it had been merged into the `Target` domain, which wasn't immediately obvious to me.

The `targetCreated` event is probably the event that listens to new worker instances. This provides the `TargetInfo` object in it's callback, which has the `targetId,` and a `type`, with a value probably along the lines of 'Web Worker' or 'Worker' (total guess though).

You could then attach to the worker process with the `attachToTarget` method, providing the `targetId`. On a successful attach, you can then send messages to it. In your case, you could send a command to listen for the `scriptParsed` event with the callback being the `Debugger.setScriptSource`.

I'm not too sure on the timing of all these events. It's entirely possible that all of this will be happening too late, but the idea is worth a shot.

I'll have a play with this when I get a moment. If it works, I'll publish something about it. If it doesn't, will investigate further.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, unfortunately I can't make it work with Chrome 53 (have to use Electron). I tried Target.enable and also Target.setDiscoverTargets et al but got no events. Maybe a newer Chrome version works which I couldn't test yet. The lack of documentation is a bit strange though, as the protocol and its viewer should be based on a JSON spec. If the feature is there it doesn't look production-ready.

Comment: There is no target for web workers, only for service workers.